# DalekJS Click without an ID

Tags: dalekjs

Which is the right way to instrument DalekJS to click a link without an ID but based on the href?

Example:

Submit a form and then click on a link without an ID.

.click('href[URL]')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the tutorial video (http://vimeo.com/71466029), at 8:00 he shows exactly what you need to do ;-)

```
.click('a[href="/foo.html"]')
```